# Finding an existing node with same name and replacing it

Tags: c#

```
private void SaveFile()
{
   XmlDocument doc=new XmlDocument();
   doc.Load("C:\\Test.xml");

   XmlNode Buses=doc.SelectSingleNode("//Buses");
   XmlNode oldPlateNumber=doc.SelectSingleNode("//YES-6548");

   XmlElement PlateNumber=doc.CreateElement("DUS-456");
   XmlElement VIN=doc.CreateElement("VIN");
   VIN.InnerText=textBox1.Text;

   if(oldPlateNumber!=null)
   {
      Buses.ReplaceChild(PlateNumber,oldPlateNumber);
   }
   else
   {
      PlateNumber.AppendChild(VIN);
      Buses.AppendChild(PlateNumber);
   }
   doc.save("C:\\Test.xml"}
```

So the code is supposed to make an element under Buses called Plate Number which has another subelement called VIN.

I want to make a new element under PlateNumber if that PlateNumber doesn't exist. If it exists, I want to rewrite the PlateNumber using ReplaceChild.

Weird thing is that when I get rid of if clause, Buses.ReplaceChild(PlateNumber,oldPlateNumber) replaces the existing node. But when I try to detect if the node exists, VIN is empty.

Anyone shed a light on this why? Am I doing it wrong to detect the existing node?

Also, I just found out about LINQ. Is it a lot easier to not use XmlDocument anymore?

Thanks

Edit---------

When Buses.ReplaceChild is in if clause
[image]

Comment: Can you post a minimal sample of your xml?

Comment: " Is it a lot easier to not use XmlDocument anymore?" - Yes, LINQ to XML is a much cleaner API.

Comment: The Linq objects @JonSkeet is refering to would be XDocument, XElement, and XAttribute.  XmlDocument is an older Xml Framework that you would only need to use if you are stuck on .Net 2 or earlier.

Comment: from my experience a single solution like Linq or other are not always satisfactory for xml handling in c#, apply the method which best suit for your case

Answer (score 1):

I thnk you have forget to save the xml before go to next step

```
        private void SaveFile()
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load("C:\\Test.xml");

            XmlNode Buses = doc.SelectSingleNode("//Buses");
            XmlNode oldPlateNumber = doc.SelectSingleNode("//YES-6548");

            XmlElement PlateNumber = doc.CreateElement("DUS-456");
            XmlElement VIN = doc.CreateElement("VIN");
            VIN.InnerText = textBox1.Text;

            if (oldPlateNumber != null)
            {
                Buses.ReplaceChild(PlateNumber, oldPlateNumber);
                doc.Save("C:\\Test.xml");
            }
            else
            {
                PlateNumber.AppendChild(VIN);
                Buses.AppendChild(PlateNumber);
                doc.Save("C:\\Test.xml");
            }
        }
```

Comment: oops. I fixed my code above, but I had doc.Save after if clause. That still shouldn't cause any problem right?

Comment: maybe not I think, play yourself and see the result what happen :)